# How to design an application to model a query with calculated fields

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns

I'm creating an application to be a user interface for a database.

I am using the Active Record design pattern, therefore I have coded Models to replicate the database Tables.  Everyone of my tables has an associated Model in my application

As an example, here is my TenureHistory table and its Model in my application which stores an employee start date and end date at a company.

[image: ERD for TenureHistory]

```
class TenureHistoryModel : DbConnector
{
    public int TenureId { get; set; }           // tenure_id (PK)
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; } // employee_id (FK)
    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }   // company_id (FK)
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }     // payment_type
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }     // start_date
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }      // end_date

    public static TenureHistoryModel FindById(int tenureId)
    {
        TenureHistoryModel tenure = null;

        DbDataReader dr = ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM tenure_history WHERE tenure_id = @TenureId", new Parameter("@TenureId", tenureId));

        if (dr.NextRecord())
        {
            tenure = new TenureHistoryModel()
            {
                TenureId = dr.GetInt("tenure_id"),
                PaymentType = dr.GetString("payment_type"),
                StartDate = dr.GetDateTime("start_date"),
                EndDate = dr.GetDateTimeN("end_date")
            };
            tenure.Employee.EmployeeId = dr.GetInt("employee_id");
            tenure.Company.CompanyId = dr.GetInt("company_id");
        }

        dr.Close();

        return tenure;
    }
```

But sometimes I have SQL select queries that use calculated fields, for example:

```
-- MS Access SQL
SELECT 
  employee.employee_id,
  employee.firstname & " " & employee.surname AS full_name,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  IIf(IsNull([end_date]),Date(),[end_date])-[start_date]+1 AS days_length,
  (IIf(IsNull([end_date]),Date(),[end_date])-[start_date]+1)/365 AS years_length
FROM
  employee INNER JOIN tenure_history ON employee.employee_id = tenure_history.employee_id;
```

---

My question is, for queries like the above, in my application should I create another Model for the sole purpose of this one query used in my application.

Or, should I add the DaysLength and YearsLength as properties in my TenureHistoryModel (and FullName in EmployeeModel) that would only ever get used for this particular query.

Or, is there a different/better way

Answer (score 0):

As i dont see these calculated fields in your WHERE clauses i would put these values into get-only Properties and calculate them on demand, if they are only used in some special cases.

Comment: I don't see this as a solution for me. It may work for my example shown, but I have other queries that use aggregate functions that won't work how you suggested.  Also is there a performance hit? I assume fetching and displaying 1000 records and getting the DB to do the calculations is better rather than the App